# Hierarchical Grid

Tags: gridview, visual-studio-2003, hierarchical

Please help me to create a Hierarchical grid...i wanted to a '+' button in first column of parent grid and on the click of that '+' button i wanted to show the child details...
I wanted to do this in Visual Studio 2003.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

there is an article in codeproject about this.its bit lengthy that i am not explaining it here.after trying it if you have any trouble feel free to post again,we will help.

[CParticle](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/160773/Expandable-Rows-In-GridView)